# How to compare and get data from less than 5 minutes only?

Tags: python, datetime

I have large amount of json data. how to compare less than three minutes of data. how to get the results for the last three minutes of data and otherwise skip the data.

How to compare hours as minutes using datetime module?

confused compare minutes and hour based value should i use datetime module string based compare value?

sample:

```
data = [{'EventTime': '08/18/2022 08:06:52', 'Password_change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/18/2022 08:05:10', 'Password_Change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/18/2022 08:04:23', 'Password_Change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/18/2022 05:06:52', 'Password_Change': 'Success'}]
```

code:

```
data = [{'EventTime': '08/18/2022 08:06:52', 'Password_change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/18/2022 08:04:10', 'Password_Change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/18/2022 08:03:23', 'Password_Change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/18/2022 05:06:52', 'Password_Change': 'Success'}]
for i in data:
    split_time = i['EventTime'].split(' ')[1]
    time_detail = split_time
    print(time_detail)
```

Comment: Parse the string to a `datetime` using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), then compare it to a `datetime` object of 3 minutes ago to see if it's greater or smaller…?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to split time string to get time information. Python provides us with datetime utilties

You can do something like below

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = [{'EventTime': '08/18/2022 08:06:52', 'Password_change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/18/2022 08:04:10', 'Password_Change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/18/2022 08:03:23', 'Password_Change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/18/2022 05:06:52', 'Password_Change': 'Success'}]

result = []
ref_time = datetime.now()
for item in data:
    event_time = item.get('EventTime')
    event_time_obj = datetime.strptime(event_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    diff = (ref_time - event_time_obj).total_seconds()
    
    if diff <= 300:
        result.append(item)

print(result)
```

Note: Please make sure you specify the timezone in your code based on your data. Currently ref_date is in UTC format.

Comment: if i run the code it shows an empty list

Comment: Your actual comparison is a bit… weird. You're already constructing a `ref_time` of 3 minutes ago, so to then get the difference in seconds to the parsed datetime and see if it's <= 300 is… wrong. Just do `if event_time_obj >= ref_time` or something like that.

Comment: @Angeline I have updated the answer, can you check once again. Please ensure correct timezones. 

Thanks for the heads up, while trying multiple approaches I missed the ref_time line change. I have updated it now.

Comment: @Angeline. Please try to print ref_time and see if the current time is matching your expectation. If not please pass the correct timezone to datetime.now()